# Have opening section of page full browser height, all other sections defined height.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ive got a site that is made up of a bunch of blocks all different height, but all full width. What im trying to do is make the first of these blocks be the full height and width of the browser window, with all the other blocks having the set height, like this site : http://savant.com

So far, after much trial and error ive been able to get the first block div to be full screen, but all the other blocks stack under the first one so they are not viewable. What i want to do is for the first block to be full screen, but allow a user to scroll through all the other blocks below.

Ideally ive been trying to do this with pure css, but im not even sure if thats possible so am open to JS also.

Ive make a JSfiddle of the issue here : https://jsfiddle.net/kff1swjf/

My markup is like this :

```
<div id="section1">Section 1</div><!--this one should open full height and width of the browser window-->
<div id="section2">Section 2</div>
<div id="section3">Section 3</div>
<div id="section4">Section 4</div>
<div id="section5">Section 5</div>
```

This is my css :

```
#section1 {
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
}

#section2 {
    background: blue;
    height: 150px;
}

#section3 {
    background: yellow;
    height: 300px;
}

#section4 {
    background: green;
    height: 200px;
}

#section5 {
    background: purple;
    height: 175px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is change the CSS for `#section1` to the following:

```
#section1 {
    background: red;
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
}
```

This will use `100vh` for the height, where `100vh` is the same as 100% of the viewport's height.

Here's the demo with the update: https://jsfiddle.net/bf70h42y/